# Unit Testing Directive Scope Function After Broadcast

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple directive, and in the link function is a $broadcast receiver $on. Once received, a scope function is called:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {


        $scope.createCart = function () {
             // Create cart
        }

        function getProductList() {
             // get products lists
        }


        $scope.$on('create-shopping-cart', function() {
            $scope.createCart();
            getProductList();
        });

    }
};
```

I have tried:

```
describe('<-- myDirective Spec ------>', function () {

    var scope, $compile, element, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        var html = '<my-directive"></my-directive>';
        element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);

        spyOn(scope, '$on').and.callThrough();
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(element).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should broadcast ', function () {
        scope.$broadcast('create-shopping-cart');
        scope.$digest();
        expect(element.isolateScope().createCart()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

With the above, i see error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'element.isolateScope().createCart')
```

How can i test $scope.createCart(); AND getProductList(); are called?

Comment: your directive don't seems to be having `isolated scope`, you should call `element.scope().createCart()` OR better call `scope.createCart()` one as the same thing

Comment: With element.scope().createCart() i get - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'element.scope().createCart()')

Comment: with scope.createCart() i get TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'scope.createCart()')

Comment: If i do, expect(scope.createCart).toHaveBeenCalled(); i get Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: correct, I think `spyOn(scope, '$on')` is local to your `beforeEach` function, make it global..